# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to perform a simple process of reading a csv, using python (google colab).

Apparently I am having an error with enconding, I tried some things like adding enconding = 'utf-8' and enconding = 'utf-16' ... but I was not successful.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('/.../data/teste.csv')



UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-5726c7261d47> in <module>()
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 pd.read_csv('/.../data/teste.csv')

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1889         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1890 
-> 1891         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1892         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1893 

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Use a different encoding: `encoding = "ISO-8859-1"`

Comment: Try using `utf-16` as your encoding

Comment: When I try to use utf-16 the error is this:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 176948-176949: illegal UTF-16 surrogate

Comment: When I try to use encoding = 'ISO-8859-1' the error is different:
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 5, saw 4